# equal distribution event handler timer C#

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, event-handling

I would like to fire my code based on a selected value from a drop down list of values.I want to also specify a `time range` (example below). The code I want to fire is behind `button1_Click` so id want to click that via code.

```
//Create the timer
Timer timer = new Timer();

//set it up
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); 
timer.Interval = (1000 * 60 * 5);           
timer.Enabled = true;       
timer.Start(); 

//now do stuff
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //click the button using code
}
```

Lets say I select 8 from the drop down list, that means I want to click my button 8 times, HOWEVER, the button needs to be clicked equally based on a time range.

So lets say I select:

**From**: `13:00`
**To**: `15:00`

that gives me 3 hours. I then want to divide the number that I have selected from the drop down, eg 8 by the number of hours/mins available.

In the example I expect the button to be clicked every 22.5mins.

Answer (score 0):

On the SelectedValueChanged, reset the timer. Stop it, reset the interval and start it again. Inside the event handler, execute the click method.